# why do I always get Null after I try to get the file uploaded using the component <t:inputFileUpload?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload

the code  of xhtml is below:

```
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="importForm">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <t:inputFileUpload id="upFile"
                        title="#{messages['global.label.import.browse']}"
                        value="#{attachmentAction.upFile}" storage="file"
                        maxlength="1000000">
                    </t:inputFileUpload>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:commandButton action="#{attachmentAction.upload}" value="#{messages['button.upload']}" 
                        styleClass="btnCla" onclick="return checkSelectFile();" type="submit">
                    </h:commandButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </h:form>
```

the code of Action method is below. I just want to get a excel from client.

```
public void upload(){
    try {
        jxl.Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(upFile.getInputStream());// Here , I always got Null for the value of upFile! Why?
        wb.getSheet(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

I always got Null for the value of upFile! Why?

Comment: Is this how your real code handles exceptions? You might not want to ignore them.

Comment: i am trying to use the component, just a demo for getting a excel from client.

Comment: I would avoid avoid ignoring exceptions, and in the very least would print a stack trace. What library are you using to work with excel? Is this an android program? Consider adding more relevant tags to your tag list to attract the experts in this problem.